# How to set a div (#jumbotron) the be the height of the viewport minus the height of another div (#header) which chnges dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

**Background/skill:** I am starting to test out using bootstrap 4 (first time using bootstrap) for a custom Wordpress theme. I have the basic understanding of HTML and CSS, but with the newer CSS and with any jQuery or javascript, I am fairly clueless and usually just hacking code I find online to try and make it work for me, with little understanding of how/why it works if I succeed.

Missing out a bunch of page header info link links to scripts and stuff which I do understand may eventually affect any suggested method, and just to keep it simple. For now I have the following HTML so far:

```
<div id="page" class="site">
  <div id="header" class="container-fluid">
    <div id="masthead" class="site-header row row-eq-height">
      <div id="logo" class="col-sm-4 col-md-6 col-lg-3"></div>
      <!--logo-->
      <div id="fruits" class="align-self-center d-none d-md-block col-md-3 col-lg-6"></div>
      <!--fruits-->
      <div id="social" class="d-none d-md-block col-md-3 col-lg-3"></div>
      <!--social-->
    </div>
    <!-- #masthead -->
  </div>
  <!--header-->
  <div id="jumbotron" class="row">
    <div id="notice" class="align-self-center col-md-3"></div>
  </div>
  <!--jumbotron-->
  <div id="content" class="site-content"></div>
  <!-- #content -->
  <div id="footer" class="container-fluid">
    <footer id="colophon" class="row"></footer>
    <!-- #colophon -->
  </div>
  <!--footer-->
</div>
<!-- #page -->
```

The jumbotron has a background image and a div (#notice) inside it which will float to the left with some text inside. I want the div to take up all remaining viewport space after the header. I have managed to get the jumbotron div be the height of the viewport minus the header using the following CSS:

`height:calc(100vh - 155px);`

But this only works if I know the height of the header is 155px. In reality, it changes at different screen widths and depending on content.

Is there a way to set the CSS to use a calculation for the dynamic header?
If not, do I need to use some kind of jquery or javascript? If so, I would be very grateful for some fairly detailed instructions.

Note: I do not want the #jumbotron to be the height of the page and sit behind the header div as a solution because the background image display is important.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can't know easily the height of the header in every device because it is a percentage of the height... And because it depends on a big bunch of CSS rules form BootStrap and your Wordpress theme... You will just measure it to deduct the remaining space.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  function adjustJumbotronHeight(){
    var headerHeight = $("#header").outerHeight();
    var viewportHeight = $(window).innerHeight();

    var remains = viewportHeight - headerHeight;

    $("#jumbotron").css({"height":remains});
  }

  // On page load
  adjustJumbotronHeight();

  // On resize (or mobile orientation change)
  $(window).on("resize",function(){
    adjustJumbotronHeight();
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you so very much!  Also thank you for noticing that there would be additional scripts and Wordpress/Bootstrap css. I have plugged this into the real page already and it works a charm so far :)

Comment: Only on page load... mmm... Maybe the header "reserves" more space than needed... Than when all images are fully loaded, there is space freed... Due to aspect ratio. (?) So... instead of adjusting on "document ready"... you could try it when the window and all elements are fully loaded. That would be `$(window).on("load", function(){` instead of `$(document).ready(function(){`. ;)

Comment: Or you can do both... The ready state occurs faster because it's before all images loaded. And then, like the on resize, just call the function on window loaded. That will adjust the screen faster and readjust when all images are loaded. ;) In fact... This line `$(window).on("resize",function(){` would change to `$(window).on("resize, load",function(){`

Comment: I'm so sorry. I was wrong (and thought i had deleted my comment/problem before you would see it)—Thanks so much for taking the time to reply. 

I had slightly changed the code by inserting an additional wordpress navigation element  into the #header, and this seems to be causing the problem—not your code which works as it should when the nav isn't included! :)

I'll try to figure out this other issue myself for a while before coming here for further help - if i can.

Comment: No problem ! I like those puzzles ;)

Comment: I like them when they take 30 mins-2 hours. Not 2 hours-3 days as seems to be the case for me :D haha!

Comment: Speed comes with pratice... And pratice lead to more complex problems because you want to do more... That is a spiral!